# Video of typing text on an angle

Tags: video, after-effects, video-editor, editing, transitions

I saw this video (https://pin.it/119U75R) and I want to do something like it but I don't know what it's call to search about it, so can you help me how I can search about it?
I would like to make text like typing in this way with an angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different techniques going on in this shot.

First the text was all made in 2D:
The hand-drawn text was probably made in 2D first, then [revealed with a mask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbMX20YoNTw) either line by line or using a plugin like [QuickDraw](https://aescripts.com/quickdraw/).
The printed text is being animated on character-by-character using [text animators](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/how-to/creating-animating-text.html).

Then that 2D layer has a paper layer added behind it, some drop shadow added to it as a [Layer Style](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/after-effects/using/blending-modes-layer-styles.html#layer_styles) maybe.

Then all of it is placed into 3D, with some camera moves on it ([this is an old tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBa-lOY5zEM&list=PLaIKzT89Vb0OqQR6Ud3Y6vlURl3jDM_-d&index=8), but the whole set is great for getting to grips with After Effects)

There's other stuff going on in that clip, but that's the basics of the text effects.

Comment: thank you <3
it's clear